# Determining Reynolds number

Tags: fluid-mechanics

QUESTION: Air at 35°C enters a 10 m long section of a rectangular duct of cross section 25 cm by 15 cm made of
commercial steel at an average velocity of 10 m/s.

*Take density of air and dynamic viscosity as 1.145 kg/m^3 and 1.895 x 10^-5 kg/m.s respectively.

Determine:
(a) Reynolds number

see my working here below,
[image]

[image]
[image]

i take the cross section 25cm * 15 cm as my area. I need help finding the diameter of pipe and please do confirm my workings cause i feel like its somewhat off since from my calculation above my Reynolds number is quite big.

Comment: looks ok, what makes you think something is wrong. (I'm cringing at the line where you appear to multiply `(a+b)(a+b)`, but you correct that on the next line)

Comment: Looks fine as per agentp, turbulent but that is to be expected..

Comment: Use this site and check : http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/reynolds-number-d_237.html

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. Even if you take the area to be half of the current area and reduce the velocity of air by a factor of 10, even then you will get turbulent flow.I took these numbers just to put things in perspective.

```
1.145*1*0.09375/(1.89*10^-5) ~ 5679
```